# Extending WCF DataContract just to use it in GUI layer?

Tags: winforms, wcf, user-interface, data-binding, datacontract

Is this valid? or does it smell?
What I'd want to do is:

- Have a datacontract object that holds a friendly object tree that can be saved by the service layer without the GUI not having to worry about it.
- At the GUI level I make heavy use of databinding and also have some GUI specific logic (like cloning, flagging as deleted, basic validations, INotifyPropertyChanged etc).

I'd like to extend this DataContract class so I just have to add BindingLists, or my specific GUI logic and then send this object without the need of translating it to the WCF service layer.

Maybe composition is a better approach than extending?
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't extend the DataContract class. I would create a Facade that added the extra functionality that I needed and could also handle communicating back down through the DataContract transparently.

Comment: I've just finished some tests by using composition, this way I can bind to the primitives values and let .net's databinding update that object for me, and at the time of calling the WCF service I don't need to do any translation because I already have the Contract ready to be sent. Does that sounds ok ?

Comment: @Sebastian - It sounds like you should be ok. I'm not sure how flexible it would be in the future...but it'll at least get you going.